# Why non UI thread can modify UI?

Tags: android, multithreading, debugging

Yes, it shouldn't but the thread i made in my `mainActivity` in `onCreate` can modify UI, like this :

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                someTextview.setText("Hello");
            }
        });
        thread.start();
```

I'm using android studio 2.2.2 .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: you can do it as long as you do it before the mainthread enter onResume()

Detail:

Usually you get a error like this when modifying UI from non UI thread

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
    Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

and this exception is throwed here in the `ViewRootImpl` class

```
void checkThread() {
    if (mThread != Thread.currentThread()) {
        throw new CalledFromWrongThreadException(
                "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.");
    }
}
```

the `mThread` is the main thread. After the `ViewRootImpl` instance is created, UI modify opertations will need to check thread.

So when did the `ViewRootImpl` instance is created?

android.view.WindowManagerImpl.java

```
@Override
public void addView(@NonNull View view, @NonNull ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    applyDefaultToken(params);
    mGlobal.addView(view, params, mContext.getDisplay(), mParentWindow);
}
```

android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.java

```
public void addView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params,
        Display display, Window parentWindow) {
    ...
    ViewRootImpl root;
    ...
    root = new ViewRootImpl(view.getContext(), display);
    ...
}
```

So when did the `addView` method is called?

android.app.ActivityThread.java

```
final void handleResumeActivity(IBinder token,
            boolean clearHide, boolean isForward, boolean reallyResume, int seq, String reason) {
        ...
        if (r.window == null && !a.mFinished && willBeVisible) {
            r.window = r.activity.getWindow();
            View decor = r.window.getDecorView();
            decor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ViewManager wm = a.getWindowManager();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams l = r.window.getAttributes();
            a.mDecor = decor;
            l.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_BASE_APPLICATION;
            l.softInputMode |= forwardBit;
            if (r.mPreserveWindow) {
                a.mWindowAdded = true;
                r.mPreserveWindow = false;
                // Normally the ViewRoot sets up callbacks with the Activity
                // in addView->ViewRootImpl#setView. If we are instead reusing
                // the decor view we have to notify the view root that the
                // callbacks may have changed.
                ViewRootImpl impl = decor.getViewRootImpl();
                if (impl != null) {
                    impl.notifyChildRebuilt();
                }
            }
            if (a.mVisibleFromClient && !a.mWindowAdded) {
                a.mWindowAdded = true;
                wm.addView(decor, l);
            }

}
```

.

```
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (DEBUG_MESSAGES) Slog.v(TAG, ">>> handling: " + codeToString(msg.what));
            switch (msg.what) {
                ...
                case RESUME_ACTIVITY:
                    Trace.traceBegin(Trace.TRACE_TAG_ACTIVITY_MANAGER, "activityResume");
                    SomeArgs args = (SomeArgs) msg.obj;
                    handleResumeActivity((IBinder) args.arg1, true, args.argi1 != 0, true,
                            args.argi3, "RESUME_ACTIVITY");
                    Trace.traceEnd(Trace.TRACE_TAG_ACTIVITY_MANAGER);
                    break;
                ...
            }
            Object obj = msg.obj;
            if (obj instanceof SomeArgs) {
                ((SomeArgs) obj).recycle();
            }
            if (DEBUG_MESSAGES) Slog.v(TAG, "<<< done: " + codeToString(msg.what));
        }
```

here you can see the `ViewRootImpl` instance is created around `RESUME_ACTIVITY` event, so before the main thread handles the resume event, you are allowed to modify UI from other threads. you just need to be quick.

It is not recommended to do that though.

Comment: To build off this-  I don't think its intended behavior in the framework, but a shortcoming of the way they set up the checking.  I would not rely on this behavior not being fixed some day.

Answer (score 2):

> Why non UI thread can modify UI?

Technically, a non UI thread can do that.  But it is a really bad idea.

Why?

Because there are all sorts of problems with thread-safety if you do that.  The UI framework is designed on the assumption that it can access the UI data structures without synchronization.  (This simplifies things immensely, and removes the possibility of deadlocks between UI and non-UI threads ... which are next to impossible for a mortal programmer to anticipate.)

This can result in the worst kind of bugs; i.e. the ones that you can't test for, and you can't reproduce reliably ... or at all ... on your hardware.

The Android framework tries to protect you from doing this kind of thing to yourself ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify UI on Non-UI thread, you can do it via

1. `Activity.runOnUIThread()`
2. `Runnable`
3. `View.Post(Runnable)`
4. `AsyncTask`

In your code, you are using `Activity.runOnUIThread()`

Do a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 0):

you can not  update the UI from any thread other than the UI thread or the "main" thread.

only using :

1. `Activity.runOnUIThread(runnable)`
2. `View.Post(Runnable)`, `view.postDelayed()`
3. `AsyncTask`

the important question is why your code is modifying the UI?

probably, you are starting the `Thread` from the `onCreate()`. if you tried to run this thread inside a `Button` `onClick()` for example, your app will crash throwing 
`CalledFromWrongThreadException`